# Integer and float conversions

Tags: c++, type-conversion, ieee-754

I have some small problems regarding (implicit) type conversion in C++.

**1. float to int**

```
float f = 554344.76;
int x1 = f;
std::cout << x1 << std::endl;
```

Prints `554344` (rounding down or cutting of decimal places) but when replacing it with `float f = 5543444.76;` it prints `5543445` (rounding up). Why is it in the first case rounding down and in the second case rounding up? On top of that for huger numbers it produces completely weird results (e.g `5543444675.76` turns into `5543444480`). Why?

What is the difference between `int x1 = f;` and `long int x2 = f;`?

**2. Long int to float**

```
long int li;
float x3 = li;
std::cout << x3 << std::endl;
```

A solution to an exercise says that the values is rounded down and results in incorrect values for large numbers. If I try `long int li = 5435;` it is not rounded down. Or is the meaning that `long int li = 5435.56;` is rounded down? Second, why does it result in incorrect values for large numbers? I think long int and float have the same number of bits.

**3. char to double**

```
char c = 130;
double x4 = c;
std::cout << x4 << std::endl;
```

Why does this result in `-126` while `char c = 100;` provides the correct value?

**4. int to char**

```
int i = 200;
char x5 = i;
std::cout << x5 << std::endl;
```

This prints nothing (no output). Why? I think up to 255 the result should be correct because char can store values up to 255.

Comment: 4.check ascii code for 200 ..

Comment: 2. if you initialise floating point to int , it will ignore the decimal part .

Comment: in 1. i dont understand "replacing it with float f = 5543444.76;". Thats what is already there. What do you replace?

Comment: About 1/ the nearest number from 5,543,444.76 an IEEE 754 32bit float can represent is 5,543,445.0. See [this IEEE 754 converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

Comment: In general, you need to read about the floattng point representation. [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is a good start.

Comment: Floats are not represented as ints (because of exponent part). You only get about 24 bits of mantissa in FP32, which means a float will not be accurate under about a millionth of its value. Contrary to ints that have "exact" values until they overflow.

Comment: About the n°4 : `operator<<` on `ostream` will always interpret 8-bit integers (`char` and `unsigned char`) as ASCII characters. For example `std::cout << char(65)` will output a single character `A`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. float has only 23 bits of precision. 5543444 doesn't fit in 23 bits, so it gets rounded to closest value that fits.
2. You have uninitialized `li`, so it's undefined behavior. Perhaps you should edit the question to show the real code you are wondering about.
3. `char` is quite often signed. 130 can't be represented as signed `char`. This is probably undefined behavior (would have to check the standard to be sure, it could be implementation defined or there could be some special rule), but in practice on a PC CPU, the compiler takes the 8 lowest bits of 130 and showes them into the 8 bit signed character, and that sets the 8th bit, resulting in negative value.
4. Same thing as 3 above: 200 does not fit in signed 8 bit integer, which your `char` probably is. Instead it ends up setting the sign bit, resulting in negative value.

Answer (score 3):

## Edit: One question per post, please. Here I answer #3 and #4

> I think up to 255 the result should be correct because char can store values up to 255.

This is an incorrect assumption. ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/974f73824a6260fa))

You have potential signed overflow if a char is signed and 8 bits (1 byte). It would only have a maximum value of 127. This would be undefined behavior.

Whether a `char` is signed or not is implementation dependent, but it usually is. It will always be 1 byte long, but "1 byte" is allowed to be implementation-dependent, although it's almost universally going to be 8 bits.

In fact, if you reference any ASCII table, it only goes up to 127 before you get into "extended" ASCII, which on most platforms you'd need a wide character type to display it.

So your code in #3 and #4 have overflow.
You should have even gotten a warning about it when you tried `char c = 130`:

> warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion

Answer (score 3):

1. A float usually does not have enough precision to fully represent `5543444.76`. Your `float` is likely storing the value `5543455.0`. The cast to `int` is not where the rounding occurs. Casting from floating point to `int` always truncates the decimal. Try using a `double` instead of `float` or assign the value directly to an `int` to illustrate the difference.
2. Many of `float`'s bits are used to represent sign and exponent, it cannot accurately represent *all* values an `int` of the same size. Again, this is a problem of precision, the least significant digits have to be discarded causing unexpected results that look like rounding errors. Consider the scientific notation. You can represent a very large range of values using few digits, but only a few decimal points are tracked. The less important digits are dropped.
3. `char` may be signed or may be unsigned, it depends on your platform. It appears that `char` is signed 8 bit on your platform, meaning it can only represent values from -128 to 127, clearly 130 exceeds that limit. Since signed integer overflow is undefined, your test case might do anything, including wrapping to -126.
4. `char` variables don't print their value when passed to `std::cout`. They print the character associated with that value. See [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Note that since the value `200` exceeds the maximum value a `char` can represent on your platform, it might do anything, including trying to display a character that has no obvious representation.

Answer (score 2):

1. The nearest number from 5,543,444.76 an IEEE 754 32bit float can represent is 5,543,445.0. See [this IEEE 754 converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). So `f` is equal to `5543445.0f` and then rounded down to `5543445` when converted to an integer.
2. Even though on your specific system a `float` and an `long int` may have the same size, all values from one cannot be represented by the other. For instance, `0.5f` cannot be represented as a `long int`. Similarly, `100000002` cannot be represented as a `float`: the nearest IEEE 754 32 bits floats are `100000000.0f` and `100000008.0f`.
   In general, you need to read about the floattng point representation. [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is a good start.
3. `char` may be `signed char` or `unsigned char` according to the system you're in. In the (8bits) `signed char` case, `130` cannot be represented. A signed integer overflow occur (which is UB) and most probably it wraps to -126 (note that 130+126=256). On the other hand, 100 is a perfectly valid value for a `signed char`.
4. In the [Extended ASCII Table](http://www.ascii-code.com/), 200 maps to `È`. If your system does not handled extended ascii (if it's configured with UTF-8 for instance) or if you've got no font to represent this character, you'll see no output. If you're on a system with `char` defined as `signed char`, it's UB anyway.